# c++ Declaring a 2D array as a global variable

Tags: c++, arrays, variables, global

I am struggling to figure out how to declare a 2D Array as a global variable so i can use it in all of my methods. So far it is only declared in a single method hence why it cannot be used in other methods.I have figured out how to declare a normal string array by just typing string* array = new string[1] at the start of my code before the methods (i then alter the size of this array later on based of a variable) but i am unsure how to do it with a 2D array:

```
void WordSearch::ReadSimplePuzzle()

int columns = 9;

int rows = 9;


string **simple2DArray = new string*[columns];

for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)

         simple2DArray[i] = new string[rows];

//code that populates the array too long to post but not relevant.
```

I then have a method later on where i need to access the simple2DArray but i cannot figure out how to define it at the start of the code any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What isn't working with your current code?

Comment: simple2DArray is only defined in the scope of ReadSimplePuzzle() and i wish to use this 2d array in a different method however i am unsure how to declare it as a global variable.

Comment: *how to declare a 2D Array* -- A `string**` is not an actual 2D array of `std::string`.  In addition, your allocation method is highly inefficient and error prone if something happens while allocating the array.  You can make use of [this method to do the allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21943621/how-to-create-a-contiguous-2d-array-in-c/21944048#21944048)

Comment: When tempted to use the word "simple" in conjunction with programming, ask yourself, "Who am I trying to fool?" Then correct the syntax error by adding an "m" to the end of "Who." Using `new` and C-style arrays[] is not simple. Those are useful to library writers (although allocators are displacing `new` in practice). Kids, don't try this at home, yet. Use `std::vector`, `std::string` and other standard containers.

Comment: I was going to write some example code, but I see the green check mark. I guess it was too simple.  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am struggling to figure out how to declare a 2D Array as a global
>   variable so i can use it in all of my methods.

As with any global var, you need to declare your pointer in global space:

```
string **simple2DArray;
```

and then you can assign to it from inside your method

```
simple2DArray = new string*[columns];
```

Comment: I guess I'm getting downvoted for not condemning the use of raw pointers in OP's example. I condemn! Use vectors or at least smart pointers! There...

Answer (score 2):

If you columns and rows variables never change, you can do this:

```
const int columns = 9;
const int rows = 9;

string simple2DArray[columns][rows];
```

By statically allocating the memory, you now don't have to worry about freeing it.

---

Since you clarified that the size is not known until run-time, you will not be able to allocate the memory statically. A very simple solution would be:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> simple2DArray; // This will have size 0 at start
```

Then, in your initialization step, just do this:

```
simple2DArray.resize(rows);
for (auto& row : simple2DArray)
{
    row.resize(columns);
}
```

There are other ways to do this, of course, such as allocating all the memory in one block of size rows*columns and then exposing it as if it were a 2-d matrix but that might be overkill for your purposes.

Comment: the rows and columns are defined by working out the rows and columns of a text file so yes they dont change once found out but can also be different values based of size the text file used.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is hide the array behind a functional interface.

```
std::string const& getElement(size_t m, size_t n);
void setElement(size_t m, size_t n, std::string const& val);
```

The calling functions have the abstractions of a 2D array but they don't need to know how the it is represented in code.

In the implementation, you have various options:

1. Use a 1D array. Map the 2D indices to the right index in the 1D array.
2. Use a `std::vector`. Still need to map the indices.
3. Use a 2D array. No mapping of indices needed.
4. Use a `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>`. No mapping of indices needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking this for making it easier to solve competitive programming problems, then look at the constraints given in the question. 
For example if the matrix can be an N*N with `1 <= N <= 1000` Then you can globally declare
 `int arr[1000][1000];`

 Here's some code for a better idea.

```
//global declarations 
int N;
int arr[1000][1000];

int functionA()
{
  // some code
}

int functionB()
{
   // some code
} 

int main()
{
   // Get the input of both N and your array arr
   // Now you can use them in any where in your code 
    
}
```